# Cloud Explorer - cannot access development Blob Containers

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am developing with Azure storage locally using VS2015.  I created and accessed my development storage blob container fine.  I upload three images and have code to calculate the size of the images.

For some unknown reason, I cannot expand the Blob Containers node in Cloud Explorer any more.  I.e. Cloud explorer > Storage Accounts > (Development) > Blob Containers.  Doing so results in the following error message:

> Cloud Explorer has encountered an unexpected error: Unable to retrieve
>   child resources.

It has been working fine in the past, so not sure what's changed.  I know there are containers inside and I can seemly create one but then it doesn't show up in the list.

It works for live Azure storage accounts but not development.

Though I can still write code against this Development container - so it's there and functional but Cloud Explorer just not listing the containers i.e. no access to view files / upload file through VS UI.

Comment: I'm having this error while trying to get Logs of a Web App. It states "Cloud Explorer has encountered an unexpected error: Unable to retrieve child resources. Details: 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'relativeUrl'" Have you found solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are my steps to resolve

1. Uninstall Cloud Explorer via Extensions and Updates
2. Restart VS
3. Update the Cloud Explorer in Extensions and Updates (that apparently wasn't uninstalled)
4. Experience the catastrophic behaviour (very slow)
5. Restart VS
6. Fixed (seemingly)
7. Look into Extensions and Updates to see Cloud Explorer is disabled
8. Everything is fixed.

**Update (29/07/2018)**

If you are having trouble launching Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer (Development) e.g. blob storage and get the error message "Unable to retrieve child resources" followed by details of "A network error occurred...ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:10002" then simply (install and) **run the Azure Storage Emulator**.

Comment: That actually didn't work for me. I've uninstalled it via "Extensions and Updates", closed VS, and reinstalled Cloud Explorer from https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/84e83a7c-9606-4f9f-83dd-0f6182f13add?SRC=VSIDE . Then it worked.

Comment: I just upgraded to Azure Tools v2.9 from V2.7.  I was bracing myselft to see what stopped working this time.  This is the first problem that I have come across and your solution worked for me.

Comment: unfortunately not working for me. uninstalling the extension is also very difficult. it requires several attempts and even when it finally goes from the extensions list, you can still access an older version of the cloud explorer

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. Tried to connect from different computers and different locations. Does anyone have a working solution?
@MarkHeath, I saw your post on attaching debugger, you must have solved this issue :)

Answer (score 1):

The aforementioned solution didn't work for me.

The error went away after upgrading to Azure SDK 3.0 (using web platform installer). After that I am able to expand the child resources in App Services, and attach the debugger.

Another option that worked was using the Server Explorer to expand files/attach the debugger, but that option seems to have been turned off in 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the Storage Account Name is case sensitive to teh azure service. The client however is not.

Because of this you can connect, but when the Storage Explorer tries to enumerate the child object it will fail if the Storage Account is not entered with the proper case.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when my system-clock was accidentally set a couple of hours back in time. Just saying.