# Accessing the FHIR data in Microsoft Azure Storage explorer using the managed version

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, hl7-fhir

I am working on Azure FHIR server to load Patient resource. The template provided in the below  link is used(Managed version).

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/azure-api-for-fhir/

After installing the FHIR server and Azure api for FHIR, I have followed the steps provided in the below link to add data to the Cosmos DB.

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/healthcare-apis/access-fhir-postman-tutorial
```

These steps have helped to add the patient resource to the Cosmos DB. But I am not able to view the added data in the Microsoft Azure storage explorer(Version 1.11.0). I am getting below error.

[Error while trying to open the DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkxWE.png)

Steps tried,

1. deleted the storageExplorer folder under %appdata/roaming.
2. Deleting "Cookies" & "Cookies-journal" files from %appdata%\storageexplorer then relaunching app

Any help would be appreciated, Thank you  in Advance.

Comment: I am not sure this is really a FHIR server related question. It looks like you are having problems accessing the data in the cosmos db emulator in general? I would recommend re-installing the cosmos emulator and verify that it works (you can access the emulated cosmos DB from storage explorer) before moving forward to debug the FHIR server. If you continue to have problems ask the question to Cosmos DB without the FHIR label.

Comment: yes, right. I am having issues in accessing the data in the Cosmos DB using the emulator. Tried to install the older versions , but still facing the issues to access the data.

Comment: May you check to make sure port 8081 is not already being used by another service on your machine. 

See if the solutions in this SO thread might work for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39318480/cloud-explorer-cannot-access-development-blob-containers?rq=1

Maybe also checkout this post on msdn about using non standard ports with storage explorer - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7eba4289-4ff9-4e63-b5d2-77298d0238b1/storage-explorer-with-non-standard-ports?forum=windowsazuredata

Hope one of these helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the Microsoft Support Escalation engineer, replied as below.

In the **managed version** of Azure API for FHIR service, the only way to access the data is through RESTful APIs using Postman etc. You will not be able to view the data using Data Explorer on the CosmosDB blade.

To view the data in the data explorer, we need to use Open Source deployment version

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/healthcare-apis/fhir-oss-portal-quickstart

Template for open source can be found in the below URL.

https://github.com/Microsoft/fhir-server/blob/master/docs/DefaultDeployment.md

After following the steps, I am able to view the data in the data explorer of Cosmos DB.